# Locked out of my own Question

Tags: discussion, bug

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450942/sign-language-translator-project) and it said something about it being similar to my previous question and now I have two comments on it but I can't read them. I tried to access it while logged out but it still won't work

On Chrome it says

> This webpage is not available

On Firefox it says

> The connection was reset

Comment: Could you link to the question in question, or screen shot the notification about the two comments

Comment: here is the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450942/sign-language-translator-project)

Comment: I can see two comments just fine...

Comment: As can I, what do you see when you click the link? A 404, an error message?

Comment: Hi have tried it in your responses tab which their on your profile panel

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? Have you tried a hard refresh? I think this is a browser issue, nothing on our end.

Comment: depends. on chrome it says page not available. on firefox it says the connection was reset. I am using Windows 7

Comment: Clear your browser history and cookies. This looks like an issue on your end.

Comment: btw. your SO question is off topic as youre asking for a tool recommendation :P

Comment: i cleared my browser history and cookies but still not loading

Comment: Do you have problems with all questions? Or just this one?

Comment: just this one. other messages in my inbox load just fine.

Comment: @mehow It is not only OT, [it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19450942/806549) is also a self-duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19424963/806549)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Happens to me, too. So far it always was my PROXY server that did it - content filters here does not like any messages about TOR, vtunnel and similar things. Note:  I will probably not be able to revisit this question from this network now when I mentioned them.

Your situation looks exactly like mine, so consider asking your sysadmins, or adding Stack to an exception list in your internet security software.

Comment: but there are no such words in my question

Comment: @user2638268 but your proxy could be configured for other words.

Comment: @Molot you might be on to something because other people in my network can't access the question too.

Comment: This sounds like the most probable cause. But the strange thing is that I can't find anything that might cause offence to *any* such filter (and I know that they can be stupidly finicky occasionally).

Comment: @Molot you are right. I don't know what is wrong with my question but it works when i use UltraSurf.

Comment: @user2638268 glad it's solved. Finally I can see it (from home network), but it appears others already answered all doubts :D